# Trying to increase

Tags: pandas, nlp, spacy

Please see the following code. After having read in a csv file of 5000 rows, I get the error message:

```
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
nlp.max_length = 3000000
nlp.add_pipe(
    "text_categorizer", 
    config={
        "data": data, 
        "model": "sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2",
        "device": "cpu"
    }
)
```

> ValueError: [E088] Text of length 2508705 exceeds maximum of 1000000. The parser and NER models require roughly 1GB of temporary memory per 100,000 characters in the input. This means long texts may cause memory allocation errors. If you're not using the parser or NER, it's probably safe to increase the `nlp.max_length` limit. The limit is in number of characters, so you can check whether your inputs are too long by checking `len(text)`.

Is there anyway through which this can be solved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Setting `nlp.max_length` should work in general (up until you run out of memory, at least):

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
nlp.max_length = 10_000_000
doc = nlp("a " * 2_000_000)
assert len(doc.text) == 4_000_000
```

I doubt that the `sentence-transformers` model can handle texts of this length, though? In terms of the linguistic annotation it's unlikely to be useful to have single docs that are this long.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you have a suggestion for any other model that is capable of handling a larger amount of rows and is better than the spacy model?

Comment: Without knowing what you're trying to do it's hard to say, but at least for what you've described above it probably makes sense to process each row separately?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is also what I was thinking of. I am trying to process a large dataset containing amazon reviews. I want to use text classification to select reviews based on a the above text classification module. Maybe a for loop would do it?